# Can not deserialize instance of java.io.File out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, playframework

I have the error following :

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.io.File out of START_OBJECT token
```

in the line:

```
InlineResponse20041 response = Json.fromJson(wsResponse.asJson(), InlineResponse20041.class);
```

In the class `InlineResponse20041`, I have a property `java.io.File myFile`. And it's to deserialize in this property that the problem is present.

How to deserialize `java.io.File` from JSON?

Thanks

Comment: what does the json look like?  Is it valid json?

Comment: Yes I guess, it's a json like this : "goal": {
            "fileStatus": "available",
            "fileId": "B8J18ZOYRC4K9KW2",
            "fileName": "111110660906_STA_20180629_20180928.pdf",
            "fileEncoding": "pdf",
            "file": {
                "contentType": "pdf",
                "name": "111110660906_STA_20180629_20180928.pdf",
                "content": "JVDSJDSJDPJ"} ...